# Adobe Illustrator/inDesign/PS keyboard shortcuts to set selected swatch colour to White (or Black)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

In doing design work I find I very regularly use the colours black and white specifically.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to set the current selected swatch colour to White? and is there a similar one to set it to Black?

If not maybe is there a way I can have some favourite swatch colours and select them with a keyboard shortcut?

NB. I've stated Adobe Illustrator to keep the question specific, but I'm actually hopeful there is an option that I could use across the Adobe suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop and Illustrator will all go to default white and black on pressing <kbd>D</kbd>. You can then switch them using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (Illustrator) and <kbd>X</kbd> (Photoshop). InDesign works a bit differently as it doesn't use white:

- In Photoshop, your foreground colour will become white, and
  background colour will become black.
- In Illustrator, fill will become white, stroke black;
- In InDesign, fill will become `none` and stroke will become black.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much, that's exactly what I needed to know. So D to reset fill & border swathes to black and white respectively then just Shift + x to toggle between them. Wooooo!

Comment: Editing your answer, because you don't need to hit Shift in PS, you just need to hit X, but AI shift is required